# Retrieve the availability of motorbikes which are not in revision or in training

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am looking a way to retrieve the availability of motos which are not in revision or training.

I have a form named `motorbike` with 3 fields `(matriculation,  number_motorbike, status)`.

Here, I have 3 motorbikes and 1 **unavailable** `number motorbike -> 000001`.

[image]

My second form is `revision` with 4 fields `(date_revision_start, date_revision_end, garage, fk_motorbike)`.

I only have 1 motorbike in revision.

[image]

In my form `trainings` I have 2 fields `(date_sitting, fk_motorbike)`.

[image]

Here, when I add for example 1 motorbike which is in revision, there is no blocking, it's my problem.

In the form create.blade.php, Is it possible, to see only the motorbikes availables every day for example?

[image]

I really stuck on this problem... I thank in advance for your help and your time.

***Edit: 13/07/2019***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Motorbike;
use App\Training;
use App\Revision;

class TrainingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $trainings = Training::oldest()->paginate(5);
        $motorbikes = Motorbike::doesntHave('revisions')->doesntHave('trainings')->pluck('number_motorbike', 'id');
        return view('admin.trainings.index', compact('trainings'))
             ->with('i', (request()->input('page',1) -1)*5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {   

        $motorbikes = Motorbike::all();
        $motorbikes = Motorbike::doesntHave('revisions')->doesntHave('trainings')->pluck('number_motorbike', 'id');
        return view('admin.trainings.create', compact('motorbikes', 'trainings'));

    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {   

        $request->validate([
                'date_sitting' => 'required',
                'fk_motorbike' => 'required'
        ]);

        Training::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
    }
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('fk_motorbike') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="company-content">Number motorbike </label>
            <select name="fk_motorbike" id="fk_motorbike" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ old('fk_motorbike')}}"/>
              <option value="">Choice motorbike</option>
                @foreach($motorbikes as $motorbike)
                <option value="{{$motorbike->id}}" {{ old('fk_motorbike') == $motorbike->id ?  'selected' : '' }} >
                {{$motorbike->number_motorbike}} 
              </option>
                @endforeach
                {!! $errors->first('fk_motorbike', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
            </select>
          </div>
```

[image]

Comment: By "available every day", do you mean "no revision entry bound to a motorbike"?

Comment: @ Shizzen83: I must exclude revisions and sittings already taken the same day

Comment: It seems like a business rule matter. to set a motorbike as available you delete related records from revisions and training? OR you have some workfollow to finish the revision and training processes?

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if it's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to query on those motorbikes that aren't under revision and are not already in training, to produce the `id` and `name` for the dropdown list.  Something like:

```
$motorbikes = Motorbike::doesntHave('revision')->doesntHave('training')->pluck("name", "id");
```

If you need only training that conflicts in time, you can replace `doesntHave` with `whereDoesntHave()` and create a closure to filter on the dates.

*The above assumes you have relationships on your **Motorbike** model set up correctly to handle revision and training.*  If you don't, you can go a little old-school to get what you need for the dropdown for only those motorbikes that don't have training and don't have a revision.

```
// Get all motorbike ids with trainings:
$motorbikeIdsInTraining = Training::pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();
// Get all motorbike ids with revisions:
$motorbikeIdsInRevision = Revision::pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();
// Get all motorbikes
$motorbikesAll = Motorbike::all();
// Loop on all bikes to see if they are in revision or training:
$goodBikeIdsForDropdown = [];
foreach($motorbikesAll as $bike){ 
     if(!in_array($bike->id, $motorbikeIdsInTraining) && ! in_array($bike->id, $motorbikeIdsInRevision){
         $goodBikeIdsForDropdown[$bike->id] = $bike->number_motorbike
     }
 }
```

This bottom part is not at all the most efficient - it is meant to explain a way to do this if you don't have your relations set up correctly.  Highly recommend setting them up to take advantage of Laravel's real power, but this should work as a way to test your code at your current point.

Comment: Hello, I have 2 questions, i have edited my first message with 3 models are they corrects?  Then, the line `$motorbikes = Motorbike::doesntHave('revision')->doesntHave('training')->pluck("name", "id");` has been added in the function index() voir first message is it correct? Thank you

Comment: Yes, I think this will work.  I can't see all of your code / database, but give that a try now, using that code in whichever function is sending the collection of name,id ($motorbikes) to your form.  usually that would be create() or edit(), but If that's index(), then give it a try.  But remember to compact 'motorbikes' as well as trainings!  Shoot, you don't have a `date_sitting` in motorbikes, don't pluck that.  Pluck `number motorbike`, `id`

Comment: If your relations are plural (trainings, revisions), match the doesntHave strings -- so not 'training', but 'trainings' for example

Comment: I have tried this but I have an error message `$motorbikes = Motorbike::doesntHave('revisions')->doesntHave('trainings')->pluck("number_motorbike'", "id"); `  the message is `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'date_sitting' inconnu dans field list (42S22)`

Comment: Yes, see my comment 2 up.  You don't have `date_siting` on motorbikes.  make it `->pluck('number_motorbike', 'id');`

Comment: Yes, thank you, then these lines. I must to put where? On the function store() i think? `// Get all motorbike ids with trainings:
$motorbikeIdsInTraining = Training::pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();
// Get all motorbike ids with revisions:
$motorbikeIdsInRevision = Revision::pluck('fk_motorbike')->toArray();
// Get all motorbikes
$motorbikesAll = Motorbike::all();`

Comment: Nope - you're all good *without* those lines IF the pluck thing worked for you.  If your `$motorbikes` are full of what you wanted (number and id of those without revision & trainings), you can skip all of that code that I wrote.  I only wrote that part to help you understand how to do it without the relationships and the pluck().  If the relationships & pluck all work, you can skip all the rest!  :)

Comment: Ok, I now must to change my loop on the file create.blade.php? with `foreach($motorbikesAll as $bike){ 
     if(!in_array($bike->id, $motorbikeIdsInTraining) && ! in_array($bike->id, $motorbikeIdsInRevision){
         $goodBikeIdsForDropdown[$bike->id] = $bike->number_motorbike
     }` for information I have edited my first message for you show my previously loop of my file create.blade.php.

Comment: Correct, you can skip all that extra stuff now that you know your relationships are working correctly.  So you are back to `@foreach($motorbikes as $motorbike)` like you had it (and like you have now have edited it).  it's getting a little hard to see everything, but I think this is now a good solution for you based on the relationships working.

Comment: Sorry - to be clear - keep with the previous way you had create.blade.  Don't put in all that stuff with the `$motorbikesAll` - just do it like you have it in your question above.

Comment: I have edited my first message with my code, I have as message `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"` ; I have deposited a screenshot. I don't understand

Comment: The screenshot says that you are trying to pluck date_sitting.  This doesn't exist, as we have noted.  Is that the right screenshot for the error?  if so, change the pluck to `number_motorbike`.  I don't see anything showing an id non-object error?  if you @dd($motorbikes) on your blade page, does it give you the right information as expected?  Also that error is showing that you haven't compacted 'motorbikes'.  Did you send the `$motorbikes` variable through to the blade file?

Comment: I was wrong, I have edited my first message with the screenshot.

Comment: What does @dd($motorbikes) give you on the blade page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196401/discussion-between-watercayman-and-user11124425).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** It's not functional yet because of your tables schema(e.g. foreign keys) but the scope `available` fullfills your needs.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Revision extends Model
{
    public function motorbike()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Motorbike');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Training extends Model
{
    public function motorbike()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Motorbike');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Motorbike extends Model
{
    public function revisions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Revision');
    }

    public function trainings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Training');
    }

    public function scopeAvailable($query, $date = null)
    {
        $date = $date ?: date('Y-m-d');
        return $query
            ->whereDoesntHave('revisions', function ($query) use ($date) {
                $query
                    ->whereDate('date_revision_start', '<=', $date)
                    ->whereDate('date_revision_end', '>=', $date);
            })
            ->whereDoesntHave('trainings', function ($query) use ($date) {
                $query->whereDate('date_sitting', $date);
            });
    }
}
```

```
$date = '2019-07-12';
$availableMotorbikes = App\Motorbike::available($date)->get();
```

Comment: I am triying but I always have the same problem. In my dropdownlist, I can see, the motorbikes unavailables. :-(

Comment: I think so I didn't understand, what is your expected output?

Comment: I want to manage the availability of motorbikes, if I want to add a training and the motorbike is under revision or is already in training, it is a problem. see fourth screenshot. My drop-down list shows all available and unavailable motorbikes, I want to filter on available motorbikes to create a training session, more easily

Comment: Oh yeah I think I got it now, let me write it